# GCM: Get Sender ID from properties file before calling GCMIntentService parent constructor

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I store the Sender ID of Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) in a properties file stored in asset folder. I want to grab the Sender ID before calling `GCMIntentService`'s parent constructor ( `GCMBaseIntentService`'s constructor ). My current solution is:

In my default Activity, named `InitActivity` :

```
public class InitActivity extends Activity {
  public static Context appContext;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        appContext = getApplicationContext();
        // ...
```

In my `GCMIntentService` :

```
public GCMIntentService() {
        super(GCMIntentService.getSenderID());
        Log.d(TAG, "GCMIntentService SenderID : " + GCMIntentService.getSenderID());
    }

private static String getSenderID() {
    Resources resources = InitActivity.appContext.getResources();
    AssetManager assetManager = resources.getAssets();

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("config.properties");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(inputStream);
        return properties.getProperty("SENDER_ID");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Failed to open property file");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

My questions are :

1. Is it okay to save Context in static way ( will it consume memory a lot, or will it lead to memory leak ) ? Reference [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android) .
2. Is there a better way to fetch Sender ID from properties file ?
3. Is it a wise choice to put the code in Activity ?

Comment: I didn't understand the logic behind storing SENDER_ID any where.

Comment: @PankajKumar what do you mean ? I want to centralize all the settings in 1 properties file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I would recommend that you don't save a context somewhere unless you are absolutely sure that you don't save a reference to it somewhere. There's a considerate risk that you might end up [leaking a context](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html).
2. Loading the Sender ID from a properties file is one way to do it, and you seem to do it the right way. You could also put it in a config file in res/values/gcm.xml:

   yoursenderid

And retrieve it like any other string:

```
String senderid = context.getString(R.string.gcm_senderid);
```

1. Yes, I guess so, but do you really need to store a context that way? Let me suggest that you try this:

   public GCMIntentService() {
       super();
   }

   @Override
   protected String[] getSenderIds(Context context) {
       AssetManager assetManager = context.getResources().getAssets();

   ```
   String senderId = null;
   try {
       InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("config.properties");
       Properties properties = new Properties();
       properties.load(inputStream);
       senderId = properties.getProperty("SENDER_ID");
   }
   catch (IOException e) {
       System.err.println("Failed to open property file");
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return new String[] { senderId };
   ```

   }

This uses the [no argument constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService.html#GCMBaseIntentService%28%29) and the [getSenderIds()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService.html#getSenderIds%28android.content.Context%29) method to provide a context specific sender id.

Comment: quite close, but `GCMBaseIntentService` accepts 1 parameter ( Sender ID ) in constructor.

Comment: I implemented GCM in an app a few weeks ago and there was a no argument constructor. The official documentation shows two constructors as well: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService.html#GCMBaseIntentService()